# sql not connecting in node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I'm trying to connect my database with node js but it is giving me this error .
here is my code

```js
//to connect to sql
var mysql=require('mysql');
var conn=mysql.createConnection({
   
    host:"localhost",
    user:"root",
    password:"",
    database:"bns"
    
});
conn.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log("connected");
   conn.query("SELECT * FROM employee", function (err, recordset) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else { 
            console.log(recordset);
        }
        conn.close();
    });
});
```

and I'm  getting this error

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\node-demo\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\node-demo\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
at Connection.connect (C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\node-demo\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
at Object. (C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\node-demo\other.js:11:6)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
errno: -4078,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '::1',
port: 3306,
fatal: true
}
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

Comment: Are you positive there's a mysql server running and it's listening to port 3306?

Comment: it says connection refused. It must be on wrong server connection parameters, offline mysql server or network blocking your pc

Comment: try login to your MySQL shell by `mysql -u root` and found that you can do that without password

Answer (score 1):

I've had an exactly same issue.

```
var conn=mysql.createConnection({

host:"127.0.0.1",
user:"root",
password:"",
database:"bns"
});
```

try this code. I think it will work.

Now only problem i hav is why it works.. lol

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the port number by which the server has to establish a connection. In your case, you had missed the port number. The code below must eliminate the problem.

```
var conn=mysql.createConnection({
   
    host:"localhost",
    user:"root",
    password:"",
    port: 3306,
    database:"bns"
    
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.